# React HOC infinite loop when applied in routing

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, react-router-dom

I'm encountering an infinite loop when trying to render my component routes with a HOC wrapper.  The routing render method looks something like:

```
const render = (route, additionalProps) => {
const scrollActive = has(route, "scroll") ? route.scroll : true;
const Component = scrollActive
  ? withScrollToTop(route.component)
  : route.component;
return props => {
  return <Component {...props} {...additionalProps} route={route} />;
};

return (
  <Switch>
    {routes.map((route, i) => {
      return (
        <Route
          key={i}
          path={route.path}
          exact={route.exact}
          strict={route.strict}
          render={render(route, injectProps)}
        />
      );
    })}
  </Switch>
);
```

For the time-being (since it's looping out), the HOC isn't actually doing anything besides wrapping the component with another class.

```
export default function withScrollToTop(WrappedComponent) {
  const displayName = `HigherOrder.WithScrollToTop('${getDisplayName(
    WrappedComponent
  )}')`;

  class WithScrollToTop extends React.PureComponent {
    static displayName = displayName;

    static WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent;

    render() {
      const props = Object.assign({}, this.props);
      return React.createElement(WrappedComponent, props);
    }
  }

  return hoistStatics(WithScrollToTop, WrappedComponent);
}
```

Attempting to hit any route causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line: 
`render={render(route, injectProps)}` (yours do not have the final `}`).

This will trigger `render` function, it does not pass the function to children `props`.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo from removing a ternary in the render prop.  We have another function to render with a factory.  Updated original snippet to correct the missing brace.

Comment: Yes, event with correct type. You should instead call `render={this.render...}` or `render={() => this.render...}`. Your way of binding will execute the `render` function right away, not passing `render` to `props`